# NgRx - reducer is being triggered for infinite times

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-reducers

I am trying to retrieve local storage data via NgRx effect. `PATIENT_FETCH` action is dispatched to execute an effect. But having an infinite call upon calling the dispatch method in `ngOnInit` method.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/CoreJADeveloper/ngrx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpatient%2Fpatient.component.ts) demo. If you uncomment line 24 in `patient.component.ts` of given link then reducer is called for infinite times. I might be missing something in NgRx implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Effect.

```
 @Effect()
    patient: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(PatientActionTypes.PATIENT_FETCH),
        tap((action: ActionTemplate<PatientFetch>) => {
            const patient: any = this.storageService.get(STORAGE_KEY, {});
            return patientActionFactory.create<PatientFetchSuccess>(PatientActionTypes.PATIENT_FETCH_SUCCESS, patient);
        })
    );
```

The above keeps dispatching the `PATIENT_FETCH` action, and picks it up again - resulting in an infite loop. From looking at the code you probably want to return the `PATIENT_FETCH_SUCCESS` action. Therefore, you must replace the `tap` operator with the `map` operator.